# How can I use std::vector safely with mutex?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I use multithreading to read and write a global variable `std::deque<int> g_to_be_downloaded_tasks`, and I use `std::mutex` to protect concurrent access. but ThreadB can not get element after ThreadA inserts an element to this vector,

ThreadA

```
g_to_be_downloaded_tasks_mutex.try_lock();
g_to_be_downloaded_tasks.push_back(temp);
g_to_be_downloaded_tasks_mutex.unlock();
```

ThreadB: ThreadB gets 0 after using `g_to_be_downloaded_tasks.size()`

```
g_to_be_downloaded_tasks_mutex.try_lock();
if(g_to_be_downloaded_tasks.size() > 0)
{
    curr_task = g_to_be_downloaded_tasks.front();
}
g_to_be_downloaded_tasks_mutex.unlock();
```

Why `g_to_be_downloaded_tasks.size()` returns 0 ?

Comment: The mutex will prevent the two threads from accessing the deque _simultaneously_, but it does nothing to guarantee that ThreadA accesses it first and ThreadB accesses it second. In the event that ThreadB accesses it before ThreadA does, does it ever go back and check again to see if ThreadA has gotten a chance to insert to it? There's a lot of ways to get this sequencing in place like condition variables but the simplest might be to throw ThreadB in a wait-and-retry loop.

Comment: Hey, did you read the documentation on `try_lock`? Why are you using that, anyway? Please read https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex/try_lock

Comment: Especially note that it returns true or false immediately and does not guarantee that the mutex is locked. You may be trying to use the vector or deque from two threads at the same time. In fact, if your actual code looks like that I **GUARANTEE IT**.

Comment: @NathanPierson yes, if ThreadB got 0, it will try again until the result is not 0, but no matter how many times, it only get 0.

Comment: @ZanLynx yes , I should have used `lock()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are ignoring the result of `try_lock`, so you aren't meaningfully using a mutex. Your code has undefined behaviour because of a data race.

If you never want to block, use the result of `try_lock`

```
if (g_to_be_downloaded_tasks_mutex.try_lock()) {
    g_to_be_downloaded_tasks.push_back(temp);
    g_to_be_downloaded_tasks_mutex.unlock();
}

if(g_to_be_downloaded_tasks_mutex.try_lock() && (g_to_be_downloaded_tasks.size() > 0))
{
    curr_task = g_to_be_downloaded_tasks.front();
    g_to_be_downloaded_tasks_mutex.unlock();
}
```

More commonly, the producing side would wait for the lock, otherwise it is discarding work

```
{
    std::lock_guard guard(g_to_be_downloaded_tasks_mutex);
    g_to_be_downloaded_tasks.push_back(temp);
}
```

Comment: I can block ,so I think I can use `lock()` to replace `try_lock()`

Comment: @YongqiZ I'd advise using a [`std::lock_guard`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) as I show in the second example